# Can anyone explain the algorithm that OpenSSL uses to add two points on an elliptic curve?

Tags: elliptic-curves, openssl, secp256k1

I am trying to understand how OpenSSL adds points on an elliptic curve. I have understood from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76712735/where-is-the-definition-of-add-located-in-openssl) that [ossl_ec_GFp_simple_add()](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/a024ab984e540bff65d25407496c34b3567b55a7/crypto/ec/ecp_smpl.c#L613) is where the addition op works. Can anyone explain the algorithm used here? I know that it's working on Projective/Jacobian coordinates. Is it following the [algorithm](https://www.nayuki.io/page/elliptic-curve-point-addition-in-projective-coordinates#:%7E:text=Affine%20coordinates%20are%20the%20conventional,concise%20and%20easy%20to%20follow) explained here?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be using relative Jacobian coordinates (see for example [Double-and-Add with Relative Jacobian Coordinates](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/1014.pdf) by Bjorn Fay). This is not the same as the projective form used in your link.